# Too many open file Descriptors in Wildfly-18

Tags: wildfly-18

In the application code deployed in wildfly10, if the fileinputstream is not closed programatically (its a miss in the code), during the GC (G1GC) cycle, the orphan references of the opened file input streams are closed, so the number of open file descriptor is not growing.

However, after the upgrade of the wildfly10 to wildfly18, the file input streams which are not closed programatically are not getting closed during the GC (G1GC) cycle due to which the number of open file descriptors are growing.

We agree that the input streams have to be closed programatically in the application code which we did now, but would like to understand the reason behind this behavior change in wildfly18.